# Oracle Virtual Box failing to open

Tags: virtualbox

I was trying to run Oracle Virtualbox Manager but it is not working. I am getting the following error message:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Oracle DB Developer VM.

The virtual machine 'Oracle DB Developer VM' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).  More details may be available in 'C:\Users\Ornob\VirtualBox VMs\Oracle DB Developer VM\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'.

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: MachineWrap
Interface: IMachine {b2547866-a0a1-4391-8b86-6952d82efaa0}
```

How do I fix this issue ?

Comment: `More details may be available in 'C:\Users\Ornob\VirtualBox VMs\Oracle DB Developer VM\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'`....

Comment: Now I'm dying to know what it says in that logfile.

Answer (score 2):

I started virtual box in administrator mode, now it's able to start my VM

Comment: I faced this error (0x80004005; MachineWrap) after upgraded my PC with additional DRAM module. Thanks to this advice I was able to start VM using Administrator mode. After one successful launch I was able to start VM normally (without Administrator mode).

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the image is inaccessible, this may be due to several reasons but in most cases, the image has been moved to another directory by making a cut paste from the Windows Explorer.

1. go to the "Machine Manager" and click on "File".
2. Click on "Media Manager".
3. In the first tab called "Hard Drives", click on the image that is unreachable  then click on the "Release" button to remove the disk link (UUID) to the VM.
4. Now click the "Delete" button to remove the disk from the "Virtual Media Manager".
5. Now all you have to do is add your image from the storage section and start on your virtual machine.

Comment: Where can I find the "Machine Manager" ?

Comment: CTRL+D on Virtual Box

Answer (score 0):

FWIW mine was a permission problem (ubuntu box).  Looked in /var/log/syslogs and found :

```
Mar 23 14:54:54 xxxx update-notifier.desktop[2988]: ERROR: AssertionError("cannot parse ProcMaps line: Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'maps'" 
...
    dlopen("/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxRT.so",) failed:
```

Have a look at permissions in /usr, /usr/lib, /usr/lib/virtualbox
These should all be owned by root.root, in my case /usr/lib was owned by another user.

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\drivers\vboxdrv
2. Right click on VBoxDrv.inf file and select Install option
3. Restart VBox as administrator